# Python - inside except statement call continue OR raise based on if result

Tags: python, if-statement, using, continue, except

in a class I have method called "place(dictionary)" that check every object in dictionary and add it in a class variable if no exception were raised.
Based on a boolean variable called ignore_invalid I want to choose to continuing the loop with the next object in the dictionary simply avoiding to add the one that had raised an exception OR blocking the loop re-raising the exception.

The code is something like this:

```
class MyOwnException1()
    [...]
class MyOwnException2()
    [...]



[..my class definition..]

    def place(self, elements, ignore_invalid=False):
        for coordinates in elements:
            try:
                if method_checker1(coordinates):
                    raise MyOwnException1("...")
                elif method_checker2(coordinates):
                    raise MyOwnException2("...")
                else:
                    print "Current coordinates are valid. Adding them."
                    # adding the current coordinates
                    [..]
            except (MyOwnException1, MyOwnException2) as my_exception:
                print my_exception
                if not ignore_invalid:
                    print "Stop the loop"
                    raise
                else:
                    print "Continue the loop with next coordinates"
                    continue
```

This code is giving me error on the raise lines: seems I can't use the "raise" and "continue" in the same "except".
What is the best way to do that?

EDIT: my IDE had a bug in the output console; after an exception, also if ignore_invalid was true, it stopped to reproduce output.
Here a stupid and semplified example of what I did (that run correctly)
http://pastebin.com/FU2PVkhb

Comment: Can you post the exact error you're getting?

Comment: it may make more sense to execute the method_checkers conditionally on `ignore_invalid`, instead of raising a exception blindly and filtering it later

Comment: Cannot reproduce the behaviour you describe, and you're not posting the full traceback.

Comment: I found the problem. What I did was right; it was simply an Ide bug. The output console blocks output after exception printing.
Here a simplified example of what I did: http://pastebin.com/FU2PVkhb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you raise your exception in except block, then it will stop the loop. When you set ignore_invalid=True, then the loop will continue running.
That's what I understand based on what you asked. Anyway,you need to give your error traceback here.

Comment: I found the problem. What I did was right; it was simply an Ide bug. The output console blocks output after exception printing. Here a simplified example of what I did: pastebin.com/FU2PVkhb

Answer (score 0):

While I can't reproduce the error you're getting, you can avoid this and make it much more readable if you avoid throwing the exceptions in the first place:

```
def place(self, elements, ignore_invalid=False):
    for coordinates in elements:
            if not ignore_invalid:
                if method_checker1(coordinates):
                    raise MyOwnException1("...")
                elif method_checker2(coordinates):
                    raise MyOwnException2("...")
            print "Current coordinates are valid. Adding them."
            # adding the current coordinates
            #...
```

Of course, this is only functionally equivalent if your method_checkers are [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)

Comment: I found the problem. What I did was right; it was simply an Ide bug. The output console blocks output after exception printing. Here a simplified example of what I did: pastebin.com/FU2PVkhb
I did that because I need to print exception anyway and my method_checkers are not pure (also if in example one of them is pure)